# Local variable might be referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, local-variables

I've been trying to make an encryption and decryption system but I have run into a small error. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import pyperclip

def copy(data):
    question = input("Copy to clipboard? ")
    if question.lower() == 'yes' or question.lower() == 'y':
        pyperclip.copy(data)
        print("Encrypted message copied to clipboard.")
        rerun()
    elif question.lower() == 'no' or question.lower() == 'n':
        rerun()
    else:
        print("You did not enter a valid input.")
        copy(data)

def rerun():
    ask = input("\nWould you like to run this program again? ")
    if ask.lower() == "yes" or ask.lower() == "y":
        print(" ")
        run()
    elif ask.lower() == 'no' or ask.lower() == 'n':
        sys.exit("\nThank you!")
    else:
        print("You did not enter a valid input.")
        rerun()

def encrypt(key, msg):
    encrypted_message = []
    for i, c in enumerate(msg):
        key_c = ord(key[i % len(key)])
        msg_c = ord(c)
        encrypted_message.append(chr((msg_c + key_c) % 127))
    return ''.join(encrypted_message)

def decrypt(key, encrypted):
    msg = []
    for i, c in enumerate(encrypted):
        key_c = ord(key[i % len(key)])
        enc_c = ord(c)
        msg.append(chr((enc_c - key_c) % 127))
    return ''.join(msg)

def run():
    function_type = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a message? ")
    if function_type.lower() == "encrypt" or function_type.lower() == "e":
        key = input("\nKey: ")
        msg = input("Message: ")
        data = encrypt(key, msg)
        enc_message = "\nYour encrypted message is: " + data
        print(enc_message)
        copy(data)
    elif function_type.lower() == "decrypt" or function_type.lower() == "d":
        key = input("\nKey: ")
        question = input("Paste encrypted message from clipboard? ")
        if question.lower() == 'yes' or question.lower() == 'y':
            encrypted = pyperclip.paste()
            print("Message: " + encrypted)
        elif question.lower() == 'no' or question.lower() == 'n':
            encrypted = input("Message: ")
        else:
            print("You did not enter a valid input.")
            run()
        decrypted = decrypt(key, encrypted)
        decrypted_message = "\nYour decrypted message is: " + decrypted
        print(decrypted_message)
        copy(decrypted)
    else:
        print("\nYou did not enter a valid input.\n")
        run()

run()
```

It says ***local variable 'encrypted' might be referenced before assignment*** and highlights

```
decrypted = decrypt(key, encrypted)
```

under the `run()` function.

Is it because I used the variable `encrypted` in other functions? If so, how would I fix this and still maintain the functionality of my program?

I am relatively new to python so I would appreciate it if you could explain your answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> local variable 'encrypted' might be referenced before assignment

is a warning generated by the linter.

This is because the linter sees that `encrypted` is assigned values inside two if conditions

```
 if question.lower() == 'yes' or question.lower() == 'y':
```

and

```
elif question.lower() == 'no' or question.lower() == 'n':
```

however, the linter cannot know that these two if conditions are complementary to each other. So, considering the case when none of the conditions is true, the variable `encrypted` will end up uninitialized.

To get rid of this warning, you can simply initialize the variable before any of the `if` conditions with `None` value

Comment: Those two conditions are *not* complementary; that would mean one is always true (cf. `x is None` and `x is not None`). *However*, in OP's code, if neither is true, it'll *recurse* instead of proceeding, and it looks like the end of the recursion is always `sys.exit()`, so `encrypted` is never referenced while undefined. So the better solution would actually be to refactor the code; see [DeepSpace's answer](/a/43974850/4518341). But FWIW, IMO, it'd be better to add a **linter ignore** than a default value that's never actually used.

Answer (score 14):

if the `else` branch is executed then `encrypted` is not defined. The IDE doesn't know you call `run()` again.

Keep in mind this might lead to an infinite recursion so you should be using another control flow mechanism (try using a `while` loop that breaks when the input is valid). See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

Before `run()` add `encrypted = None`

Comment: That doesn't actually work. `encrypted` is a local in OP's code, so a global by the same name has no effect. Cf. [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](/q/370357/4518341)