# Variable scope difference between Python versions

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import shutil
import time
t = time.time()
exception = None
while time.time() < (t + 10.0):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree('/path-to-non-existent-directory')
        break
    except OSError as exception:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.1)
else:
    if exception:
        raise exception
```

In Python 2.7 this code is perfectly valid but in Python 3.7 I get the following warning:

```
Local variable exception might be referenced before assignment
```

In the `else` clause.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with this snippet when run in Python 3.7?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Doesn't `except OSError as exception:` set `exception` to something that isn't false?

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974798/local-variable-might-be-referenced-before-assignment-python/43974850) is related, but the answers there all say that initializing the variable before the loop should prevent the warning.

Comment: @Eric Salemi - I have tried this in Python 3.7, and it returns an error saying 'Timer', 'shutil', 'cls' and 'time' are not defined. But in Python 2.7, 'Timer' (only) appears to be not defined. You should iniitalize your variables so minimalize errors.

Comment: @Eric Salemi - Add an 'import time' to initialize the 'time' variable.

Comment: How exactly are you getting that warning? Sounds more like an overzealous linter than anything else. I can't reproduce that warning simply by *running* the code.

Comment: I get that warning in PyCharm Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, to resolve a circular reference issue caused by the introduction of the `__traceback__` attribute, an `except` target is automatically deleted at the end of an `except` block. It behaves as if you had written

```
except OSError as exception:
    pass
    del exception
```

This is documented in [PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#semantic-changes).

If you want to preserve the exception object, you should save it to a second variable:

```
except OSError as exception:
    saved_exception = exception
```

`exception` will still be deleted, but you can use `saved_exception` to inspect the exception object after the `except` block is over.

Comment: This answer perfectly explains why the original code shows no warning in Python 2.7. It feels slightly more verbose and hackish to use a second variable name but i guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a block scoped language, you can't reference a variable outside of the block in which it was defined and you can't use a new value outside of the block in which that variable was updated.

In other words, you can't reference the `exception` variable's error data outside of the `except` block, if you try to do so, the value of the `exception` variable will be `None` (which you set at the top-level).

Try moving the contents of your `else` block to the `except` block and get rid of the `exception = None` and `if exception`, like this:

```
timer = Timer(10.0)
while timer.alive:
  try:
    shutil.rmtree(cls.workspace)
    break
  except OSError as exception:
    raise exception
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

If you don't want fatal errors, you could just use the `print()` function instead of the `raise` keyword:

```
timer = Timer(10.0)
while timer.alive:
  try:
    shutil.rmtree(cls.workspace)
    break
  except OSError as exception:
    print(exception)
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Here is another example (which won't work):

```
def hello():
  message = "Hello World"

print(message)
```

Because it'll raise the the following error:

```
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

**NOTE:** I'd advice against calling your exception `exception`, because there's an error class called `Exception` and doing so could lead to confusion later on.

Good luck.

Comment: `exception` is assigned a value before the loop even begins.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: Python is not block scoped, and the problem with referring to `exception` has nothing to do with scope. [`except` targets are deleted at the end of an `except` block in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#semantic-changes) to resolve a circular reference introduced by the `__traceback__` attribute.

Comment: @LogicalBranch AFAIK only `def` and `class` keywords are creating new scope in Python. Any other keyword such as `for`, `while` or `with` do not create scope so that names created within them will be available outside of them and names created before them will be available within them.